# Parse iOS PFFacebookUtilsV4 double login to Facebook

Tags: ios, parse-platform, facebook-sdk-4.0

In our iOS app, we allow Parse anonymous users, and let them authenticate later, with a facebook login.

When we used Parse before 1.7.0 (with FB before 4.0) the login flow was:

- we first tried to link the user to his FB Account with `[PFFacebookUtils linkUser:]` 

- and if the result was a 208 error (FB user already existing), we logged in the user to this FB account with `[PFFacebookUtils loginWithPermissions:]`

It worked perfectly.

Then we updated to Parse 1.7.2 with FB v4.1, and we tried to do the same with the new methods (`linkUserInBackground:WithReadPermissions:` and `logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:`) but there is a strange issue : the app goes twice to FB to login the user: 

- when trying to link the user, the app launch the FB app or website to login the user

- when trying to login to this user, the app launch one more time the FB app or website to login the user -> this was not the case before !

Do you know what's happening and how I can get back the old behavior? It's really annoying to have the FB app opening twice!

Thanks everyone
S.

Answer (score 0):

With the new SDK version, you don't need to call both methods; the `+linkUserInBackground: withReadPermissions:` will automatically call out for authentication from Facebook's SDK, including logging in if needed. Just one call to `+linkUserInBackground: withReadPermissions:` should do it.

Further reading from the `PFFacebookUtils` Class Documentation:

> **Discussion**
>
> This method delegates to the Facebook SDK to authenticate the user, and then automatically links the account to the PFUser. It will also save any unsaved changes that were made to the user.

Comment: I don't think so. There is no difference in the SDK with that...
The `+linkUserInBackground:withReadPermissions:`will return a 208 error code ("user already exists and cannot be linked to"). So I have to change user instead of linking, by login in.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Using logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions: for different devices I have double entries in Parse for the user with same email-Id.Do you face something like this also ?